# file or image migrate from drupal 6 to drupal 7 using Migrate D2D module?

Tags: media, migrations

I am using [migrate_d2d](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module to migrate my Drupal 6 website to Drupal 7, I succeed to transfer every thing except for images.

I read the new documentation sever times and I managed to migrate the files into the file_managed but I cant link them with the nodes any hints or examples will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your migrate register function define the files table migration.

```
/**
 * Migrate files table
 */
// The description and the migration machine name are also required arguments,
// which will be unique for each migration you register.
$file_arguments = $common_arguments + array(
  'description' => t('Migration of files from Drupal 6'),
  'machine_name' => 'Files',
  'source_dir' => '/var/www/drupal6/files/xxxx/',
);

// We just use the migrate_d2d D6 migration class as-is.
Migration::registerMigration('DrupalFile6Migration', $file_arguments['machine_name'],
$file_arguments);
```

Then in your node migration class set the files migration as the source.

```
// Map the image field to the new image field, base this on the Files migration
// to map the files to the imported files table.
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'field_image')
  ->sourceMigration('Files');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
  ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks ,I think this will do very well I was missing                  $this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
  ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');                   will try  it and come back to you

Comment: Does this work also for user profile pics?

Answer (score 3):

Migrating images and files are similar. Check this:
[Migrate Contents from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Using Migrate 2](http://miss-hana.com/migrate-contents-from-drupal-6-to-drupal-7-using-migrate-2/)

Here's the pieces of code for images and files migration. You can put it in your migration class and remember to change the database name, field names, urls to yours.

```
<?php
// Add other source fields which may be populated in prepareRow()
$source_fields = array(
  'image_filename' => t('img_filename'),
  'attachments_filename' => t('attachments_filename'),
  'attachments_filepath' => t('attachments_filepath'),
  'attachments_description' => t('attachments_description'),
);

// Create a MigrateSource object, which manages retrieving the input data.
$this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $source_fields);

$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'image_filename');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:source_dir')->defaultValue('http://DOMAINNAME.COM/sites/default/files/THE_DIR_YOU_PUT_IMAGES');

$this->addFieldMapping('field_attachments', 'field_attachments');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_attachments:source_dir', 'field_attachments_filepath');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_attachments:description', 'field_attachments_description');

public function prepareRow($current_row) {
  // Set image data for the image fields.
  $query = db_select(SOURCE_DATABASE . '.content_type_NAME', 'i')
  ->condition('i.vid', $current_row->vid, '=');
  $query->join(SOURCE_DATABASE . '.files', 'f', 'i.field_image_fid = f.fid');
  $query->addField('f', 'filename');
  $result = $query->execute();

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $image = array(
      'filename' => $row->filename,
    );
    $current_row->image_filename = $image['filename'];
  }

  // Set file data for the attachment file fields.
  $query = db_select(SOURCE_DATABASE . '.content_field_attachment', 'a')
    ->fields('a', array('field_attachment_data'))
    ->condition('a.vid', $current_row->vid, '=');
  $query->join(SOURCE_DATABASE . '.files', 'f', 'a.field_attachment_fid = f.fid');
  $query->addField('f', 'filename');
  $query->addField('f', 'filepath');
  $query->orderBy('a.field_attachment_fid', 'ASC');
  $result = $query->execute();

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $field_data = unserialize($row->field_attachment_data);
    $field = array(
      'filename' => $row->filename,
      'filepath' => str_replace($row->filename, '', $row->filepath),
      'description' => $field_data['description'],
    );
    $current_row->attachments_filename[] = $field['filename'];
    $current_row->attachments_filepath[] = 'http://DOMAINNAME.COM/' . $field['filepath'];
    $current_row->attachments_description[] = $field['description'];
  }
}
?>
```